# How to properly setup redis for session store

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis

I am trying to setup Redis Store like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
.......
.......
var session = require('express-session');
var redis = require("redis").createClient();
var RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({
     host: 'localhost',
     port: 6379,
     client: redis
   }),
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

But using like this the passport.js wont work and the `express-flash` will throw an error: `Error: req.flash() requires sessions.

I believe Redis is not working at all.

I am very confuse with the configuration also, should i put localhost in the host key? I am using Cloud 9, not my localhost.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I can help you with passport.js and express-flash, but this is how I've setup my session with express, redis and socket.io :

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
............
var cookieSecret = "secret phrase";
var sessionMiddleware = session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 6379,
        prefix: 'sess'
    }),
    secret: cookieSecret,
    cookie: {httpOnly: true, secure: true}, //I'm using https, so you should remove secure: true
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});
.....
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser(cookieSecret));
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
....
var io = require('socket.io')(https);
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("connected");
    console.log(socket.request.session);
});
```

Hope this could help a bit

Comment: i am also using https, i am going to try this and i tell if worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Yes, chances are you do not have a Redis server running for the client you created. Try installing and running redis-server on your machine, that did the trick for me.